# WP Blog Page Problems - Been stuck for a week

Tags: posts, blog-page

So I have my site in maintenance mode. I am almost done but have been stuck for over a week and not sure what to do.

I have a site with multiple pages one of which is my blog page.

If I set the setting - reading to static with the homepage as HOME and the posts page to BLOG, my BLOG page only has the posts with NO sidebar/widgets...

Now if do not set the reading for my BLOG page, I get my side bar widgets but NO POSTS...for my BLOG PAGE which isn't good.

I have been researching all week and literally at a dead end. I was hoping to make my site live this past Monday.

Any help would be amazing!!!

Using TESSERACT theme.

Comment: Unless you've hacked the theme, that is apparently how the theme works. Questions specific to particular themes or plugins are off topic here though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at your page.php file, where you need to add a php code calling the sidebar.php file. If that doesn't work, try using Underscores to design your website. It's a base theme for WordPress. It's only the default files with no customization. You have to design everything from scratch, but I've never had any problems with it. If you want to, I can take a look and see what's going on. Just message me.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will look further at my page.php file.